# IOIO-OTG ytai device_bootloader code gives error

Tags: ioio

I am trying to build the device-bootloader code from https://github.com/ytai/ioio/tree/master/firmware/device_bootloader in MPLAB X IDE v6.10 with the XC16 compiler but I get an error that says: Options have been disabled due to restricted license. I am new to programming and I can't figure out what to change or do. Can someone help me?